# How Do I run PHP function once file is uploaded

Tags: php, function

I have a PHP script that allows me to send a pdf file to it and it saves the PDF file locally.

```
<?php 
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'upload/');
$img = $_POST['image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/pdf;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . 'image.pdf';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

How do I run a function once the file has been saved?

Comment: use `$success` in you if condition ?

Comment: I have tried this already but the, if statement runs before the file, has been saved. How do I run a function once the file has been saved?

Comment: php scripts are processed in a sequencial, synchron manner. So that condition will only get evaluated once the statement before has _fully_ been processed. If the command before that is to save the file, then the condition will only get processed once that task has been fully done. That is because otherwise the return value of that call would not make any sense... Actually trying to get things done the other way 'round is the big issue. For you the simple, synchron processing is exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi thanks it works now !